# How to append dictionary in dictionary same key

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I want to create dictionary to send to API server like:

```
var member = ["Member":["Name":"John"],["ID":"001"],["Name":"Andy"],["ID","002"]]
```

How to use in Swift `for` loop?

I use:

```
member.updateValue([["Name":"Chris"],["ID","004"]], forKey: "Member")
```

It prints:

```
["Member":["Name":"Chris"],["ID","004"]]
```

Comment: `["Member":["Name":"John"],["ID":"001"],["Name":"Andy"],["ID","002"]]` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you change you dictionary structure 
the you can append new element

```
var member = ["Member":[["Name":"John"],["ID":"001"],["Name":"Andy"],["ID","002"]]]
member["Member"]!.insert((["Name":"Chris"],["ID","004"]), at: 0)
print("member = \(member)")
```